# Correcting x-values in matplotlib with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

numbers = [0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 5, 3, 2, 6, 7, 9, 11]

x = 0
for current, next in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]):
    if (current < next):
        up_bar = patches.Rectangle((x,current), 1, next-current, fc='green')
        ax1.add_patch(up_bar)
    else:
        down_bar = patches.Rectangle((x,current), 1, next-current, fc='red')
        ax1.add_patch(down_bar)
    x += 1

ax1.set_xticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
ax1.set_yticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
plt.show()
```

^This plots:
[image]

Though this is how I want it:
[image]

x always shifts one unit to the right. What I want is for it to only shift one unit to the right when its going down(red bar) and going up(green bar).
Does anyone know how to do it? :)

Comment: You add 1 to `x` at each iteration: `x += 1`. How do you expect `x` _not_ to increase?

Comment: I have tried removing that part, the x will will always be 0 which is not what I want.

Comment: So, make it change only when you want to. You are the coder, you are in full control.

Comment: I won't ask if I knew how to do it. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce a variable `old_current` (not the best name, though) and check whether this your numbers have "made a turn". Only in this case you should increase `x`. The following should fit your needs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

numbers = [0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 5, 3, 2, 6, 7, 9, 11]

x = 0
old_current = 0
for current, next in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]):
    if (current < next):
        if (old_current > current):
            x += 1
        up_bar = patches.Rectangle((x,current), 1, next-current, fc='green')
        ax1.add_patch(up_bar)
    else:
        if (old_current < current):
            x += 1
        down_bar = patches.Rectangle((x,current), 1, next-current, fc='red')
        ax1.add_patch(down_bar)
    old_current = current

ax1.set_xticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
ax1.set_yticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
ax1.set_xlim(0,12)
ax1.set_ylim(0,12)
plt.show()
```

[image: Bar graph]